# Where is the Run Script and Build Phase in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, applescript, carthage

To get Carthage set up, the [documentation](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/README.md) says that you need to add a Run Script.

> **On your application targets’ “Build Phases” settings tab, click the
>   “+” icon and choose “New Run Script Phase”.** Create a Run Script in
>   which you specify your shell (ex: bin/sh), add the following contents
>   to the script area below the shell:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
> ```
>
> and add the paths to the frameworks you want to use under “Input
>   Files”, e.g.:
>
> ```
> $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Box.framework
> $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Result.framework
> $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/ReactiveCocoa.framework
> ```
>
> This script works around an App Store submission bug triggered by
>   universal binaries and ensures that necessary bitcode-related files
>   and dSYMs are copied when archiving.

However, I can't find the Build Phases tab anymore or Run Script in the Build Settings search. The [Xcode 8 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html) mention

> Xcode 8 provides completely rewritten AppleScript support. A new
>   scripting dictionary provides the ability to automate Xcode workflows.

Does that mean there is no more Run Script? I looked at [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html) but honestly it looks overwhelmingly complex. Do I need to learn AppleScript just to add the simple one liner that I used to do in Xcode?

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

It is still there. Make sure you click everywhere indicated in red in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Too intuitive for an Apple UI....    hahaha..   Thx a lot... I spent 10 minutes clicking through without success... thx...

Answer (score 0):

Carthage maintainers updated README, it is necessary to add output paths too to prevent useful copying of frameworks. I have released simple script named [Carting](https://github.com/artemnovichkov/Carting) to automate these steps.