# SwiftUI preview stuck on "automatic preview updating paused"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I try to add a simple out of the box SwiftUI view to my existing project and attempt to resume the preview nothing happens. I'm unable to see the preview no matter what. It does work for new projects though.

My setup:

- Xcode 11.3
- MacOS Catalina 10.15.2
- Target iOS 13

I have tried fixing it by removing my build phases scripts (as suggested in a different post) but it didn't work.

This is my view's Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it is highly unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: Happened to me as well

Comment: Have a look here, that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58490010/swiftui-automatic-preview-updating-paused-always

Comment: Happened to me as well. Have you found a way to fix it?

Comment: Actually it happened in one project only.
A newly created one has previews working 

Comment: I've fixed my issue by setting up my project environment from scratch using the source code from repo ‍♂️ Still have no idea what caused it.