# Xcode 13.2.1 Preview Not Working but Simulator Works

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode13.2

My Xcode `Version 13.2.1 (13C100)` got an unknown issue. I did several things like delete Xcode, new install Xcode, restore from backup nothing make any change! Currently, the project can be built and run in the simulator, but not in the preview window! it gives a message:

`Cannot preview in this file - Timed out waiting for connection to DTServiceHub after 15.0 seconds.`

What is the issue here any idea?
iMac becomes very slow when I taped the resume button.
Please Help!

[image]

Comment: Do the tests run and compile? I’ve had that problem if the tests can’t run

Comment: @Jake Yes, everything runs except preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suddenly It fixed**, maybe the last update from apple through a software update called "Command Line Tools for Xcode". Before I have also tried a fresh OSX installation but the issue has not gone at all.

```
Check Software Update from system preference.
```

Thanks to the great community.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and was solved when I turned of **Automatically refresh canvas**

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: This works on Xcode 14.2. Interestingly when I turn this off, preview loads instantly. With this on, it takes forever to build for previews (and that build fails). If I turn this on again, I get buid error in preview again. Strange.

Comment: Thank you for this. This works on Xcode 15.3 even though I had a different error: Compiling failed: unexpected input file

Answer (score 4):

For me, it worked when I changed the device to Any iOS Device(Arm 64) for the preview

Comment: nothing worked but this simple change did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Clicking on the "Diagnostics" button on the failed preview pane.
2. Copy the ".pcm" file path. It looks like something similar to "/var/folders/aa/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/C/clang/ModuleCache/12345ABCDE/MyTest-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pcm"
3. Run the following command to remove the .pcm file in the Terminal app (replace the path using the specific path you copied from the Diagnostics log obtained in the step above:

   rm -rf /var/folders/aa/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/C/clang/ModuleCache/12345ABCDE/MyTest-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pcm

References:

1. https://support.macincloud.com/support/solutions/articles/8000098646
2. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696908

Comment: maybe this is not the same issue. my xcode preview window message- Cannot preview in this file - Timed out waiting for connection to DTServiceHub after 15.0 seconds.

Comment: Unreal! For over a week I've been working without a preview. Anything I tried didn't work. Contacted Apple and still sending reports. Now it's working again.

Comment: This is an easier delete of the whole cache:
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)clang/ModuleCache"

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot]

on a Mac with apple silicon chip

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Click on Xcode app
2. Get info
3. Check "open using Rosetta"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

No preview with diagnostic : "Cannot preview in this file - Timed out waiting for connection to DTServiceHub after 15.0 seconds".

Tried the solutions found on the internet, without success.

I switched to macOS beta 12.3 and Xcode 13.2.
And now there is the preview...

Answer (score 0):

The below solution has worked for me:

Running a preview for a project having scenedelegate or appdelegate which worked and then i tried running preview for app protocol style project which was not working earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue; it seems that creating a new SwiftUI file refreshes the preview and then it begins to work again.