# Remove Framework Maintained by Carthage Build Settings

Tags: ios, carthage, build-settings

I am trying to remove and delete the Mapbox Framework added through Carthage which was crashing.

I followed [these instructions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091537/uninstall-remove-carthage-from-ios-xcode-project)

After doing all of the above, however and searching for carthage in Find as instructed, I found the following reference in Targets BuildSettings All:

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS
```

In Targets, Build Settings All under Framework Search Paths, I see the attached image and if I hover over the three references, the top one, the debug and release, it shows the above code.

[image]

My question is what exactly do I delete?  Do I delete all three entries here, Framework Search Paths, Debug and Release?  The lines or values in the boxes?

I am very unfamiliar with these settings and don't want to mess anything up. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably remove all the values in the boxes without any issues but as you were just removing Carthage and we don't know what the rest of the project setup is, it's probably best to remove only the last entry (with the Carthage path).

Double click on the highlighted box in the same row as Framework Search Paths and select the Carthage row in the popup box. You can then click the '-' button at the bottom left. These are just references off where frameworks are found within your project.